# freezing haskell STrefs

Tags: haskell, data-structures, reference, mutable, freeze-thaw

I would like to implement a Doubly Connected Edge List data structure for use in Haskell.  This data structure is used to manage the topology of an arrangement of lines in a plane, and contains structures for faces, edges, and vertices.

It seems to me like a good interface to this data structure would be as a type `Arrangement`, with functions like

```
overlay :: Arrangement -> Arrangement -> Arrangement
```

but the usual implementation relies heavily on references (for example each face has references to the adjacent edges).

It seems to me that the ideal way for this to work would be similar to the way mutable and immutable arrays do: the internals of the `Arrangement` data structure are implemented as functional data structures, but the operations that mutate arrangements "unfreeze" them to create new mutable instances within a monad (ideally using COW magic to make things efficient).

So my questions are:

(1) is there a way to freeze and unfreeze a small heap like there is for arrays?
(2) if not, is there a better approach?

Comment: I guess you are not interested in the usual tying-the-knot tricks, but something more low-level.

Comment: I have an interest in creating a similar data structure in Haskell. The only 2 ways I understand to do it are using a tying the knot approach which is very elegant but inefficient to modify, or using an ID based approach with a map type data structure (indirection) which seems unsatisfying from an elegance point of view but probably works well. If you have a different approach in mind, I would like to hear more.

Comment: Have you looked at Martin Erwig's Functional graph libary? (http://web.engr.oregonstate.edu/~erwig/fgl/haskell/)

Comment: I just read the paper describing FGL, and it seems like an interesting approach.  I don't think I can use FGL directly, but perhaps I can implement my graphs in the same way.  Thanks ja!

Comment: can you just use arrays as generalized refs to implement your structure?

Comment: Yes, I think it's possible to do it that way, but you lose type information.  All refs become ints, so you need to keep track of what array you should dereference a given integer in.

Answer (score 1):

This might be what you are looking for. Loops should work fine.  A simple example involving a loop appears first.

```
data List a t = Nil | Cons a t deriving (Show, Functor, Foldable, Traversable)
runTerm $ do
  x <- newVar Nil
  writeVar x (Cons 'a' (Var x)))
  return $ Var x
```

And now, the code.

```
{-# LANGUAGE
    Rank2Types
  , StandaloneDeriving
  , UndecidableInstances #-}
module Freeze
       ( Term (..)
       , Fix (..)
       , runTerm
       , freeze
       , thaw
       , Var
       , newVar
       , writeVar
       , readVar
       , modifyVar
       , modifyVar'
       ) where

import Control.Applicative
import Control.Monad.Fix
import Control.Monad.Trans.Class
import Control.Monad.Trans.Reader
import Control.Monad.ST

import Data.STRef
import Data.Traversable (Traversable, traverse)

data Term s f
  = Var {-# UNPACK #-} !(Var s f)
  | Val !(f (Term s f))

newtype Fix f = Fix { getFix :: f (Fix f) }
deriving instance Show (f (Fix f)) => Show (Fix f)

runTerm :: Traversable f => (forall s . ST s (Term s f)) -> Fix f
runTerm m = runST $ m >>= freeze

freeze :: Traversable f => Term s f -> ST s (Fix f)
freeze t = do
  xs <- newSTRef Nil
  f <- runReaderT (loop t) xs
  readSTRef xs >>= mapM_' modifyToOnly
  return f
  where
    loop (Val f) = Fix <$> traverse loop f
    loop (Var (STRef ref)) = do
      a <- lift $ readSTRef ref
      case a of
        Both _ f' ->
          return f'
        Only f -> mfix $ \ f' -> do
          lift $ writeSTRef ref $! Both f f'
          ask >>= lift . flip modifySTRef' (ref :|)
          Fix <$> traverse loop f

thaw :: Traversable f => Fix f -> ST s (Term s f)
thaw = return . loop
  where
    loop = Val . fmap loop . getFix

newtype Var s f = STRef (STRef s (Many s f))

newVar :: f (Term s f) -> ST s (Var s f)
newVar = fmap STRef . newSTRef . Only

readVar :: Var s f -> ST s (f (Term s f))
readVar (STRef ref) = fst' <$> readSTRef ref

writeVar :: Var s f -> f (Term s f) -> ST s ()
writeVar (STRef ref) a = writeSTRef ref $! Only a

modifyVar :: Var s f -> (f (Term s f) -> f (Term s f)) -> ST s ()
modifyVar (STRef ref) f = modifySTRef' ref (Only . f . fst')

modifyVar' :: Var s f -> (f (Term s f) -> f (Term s f)) -> ST s ()
modifyVar' (STRef ref) f = modifySTRef' ref (\ a -> Only $! f (fst' a))

data Many s f
  = Only (f (Term s f))
  | Both (f (Term s f)) (Fix f)

fst' :: Many s f -> f (Term s f)
fst' (Only a) = a
fst' (Both a _) = a

modifyToOnly :: STRef s (Many s f) -> ST s ()
modifyToOnly ref = do
  a <- readSTRef ref
  case a of
    Only _ -> return ()
    Both f _ -> writeSTRef ref $! Only f

data List s a = Nil | {-# UNPACK #-} !(STRef s a) :| !(List s a)

mapM_' :: Monad m => (STRef s a -> m b) -> List s a -> m ()
mapM_' _ Nil = return ()
mapM_' k (x :| xs) = k x >> mapM_' k xs
```

Answer (score 0):

Not that the safe versions of `freeze` and `thaw` make complete copies of the array, so aren't necessarily that efficient. Of course, making a complete copy of an array of refs is arguably an optimization over making a complete copy of a structure through walking it and recursively pulling things ou of `MVar`s, etc.

Another approach to take would be something similar to that of `Repa` -- represent operations over your structure algebraically, and write a `run` function that optimizes, fuses, and then executes all in one pass. Arguably this is a more functional design. (You can use unsafe operations under the covers even, to make reification happen on-demand rather than explicitly).